# Gridview row validation in javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, validation, gridview

I have gridview in which I want to validate my two columns as such.

In first column say there will be 150Kg quantity,
then user should not be able to add value more than 150, as it is greater and it should not accept it.

Kindly suggest how to do this in javascript.

```
<cc1:Grid ID="GrdConfirmation" EnableTypeValidation="true" runat="server" Width="100%"
    ShowFooter="false" AllowAddingRecords="true" AllowSorting="false" AutoGenerateColumns="false"
    FolderStyle="../Styles/Grid/style_12">
    <ClientSideEvents OnClientSelect="GrdConfirmation_OnClientSelect" />
    <Columns>
        <cc1:Column ID="Column1" DataField="MKEY" HeaderText="Select" ReadOnly="true" Width="3%"
            runat="server">
            <TemplateSettings TemplateId="gtchkConfirm" HeaderTemplateId="HTConfirm" />
        </cc1:Column>
        <cc1:Column ID="Sr_No" DataField="Sr_No" HeaderText="Sr No" Visible="false" Width="0%">
            <TemplateSettings TemplateId="tplNumbering" />
        </cc1:Column>
        <cc1:Column ID="col_save_srno" DataField="save_srno" HeaderText="Sr.No" Visible="true"
            Width="3%" Align="center">
        </cc1:Column>
        <cc1:Column ID="Line_Id" DataField="Line_Id" HeaderText="Line id" Visible="false"
            Align="left" Width="0%">
        </cc1:Column>
        <cc1:Column ID="Item_Mkey" DataField="Item_Mkey" HeaderText="Item Mkey" Visible="false"
            Align="center" Width="0%">
        </cc1:Column>
        <cc1:Column ID="Item_Code" DataField="Item_Code" HeaderText="Item Code" Visible="true"
            Align="left" Width="6%">
        </cc1:Column>
        <cc1:Column ID="Item_Desc" DataField="Item_Desc" HeaderText="Item Description" Visible="true"
            Align="left" Width="13%" Wrap="true" HeaderStyle-Wrap="true">
        </cc1:Column>
        <cc1:Column ID="Lot_Batch_No" DataField="Lot_Batch_No" HeaderText="Lot / Batch No."
            Visible="true" Align="left" Width="7%" Wrap="true">
        </cc1:Column>
        <cc1:Column ID="Exp_Dt" DataField="Exp_Dt" HeaderText="Exp Date" Visible="true" Align="left"
            Width="7%" Wrap="true">
        </cc1:Column>
        <cc1:Column ID="Qty" DataField="Qty" HeaderText=" Quantity" Visible="true" Width="6%"
            Align="left">
        </cc1:Column>
        <cc1:Column ID="Bx_Bg" DataField="Bx_Bg" HeaderText="Boxes/Bags" Visible="true" Width="6%"
            Align="left" HeaderAlign="left">
        </cc1:Column>
        <cc1:Column ID="Net_Wgt" DataField="Net_Wgt" HeaderText="Net Weight" Visible="true"
            HeaderAlign="center" Width="7%" Align="center">
        </cc1:Column>
        <cc1:Column ID="NO_OF_PALLETS" DataField="NO_OF_PALLETS" HeaderText="No Of Pallets"
            HeaderAlign="center" Visible="true" Align="center" Width="6%" Wrap="true">
        </cc1:Column>
        <cc1:Column ID="Default_Allot" DataField="Default_Allot" HeaderText="Allocated Storage Bin No."
            Visible="true" Width="10%" Align="center" Wrap="true">
        </cc1:Column>
        <cc1:Column ID="Confirmed_Allot" DataField="Confirmed_Allot" HeaderText="Confirmed Storage Bin No."
            Visible="true" Width="10%" Align="center" Wrap="true">
            <TemplateSettings TemplateId="PlainEditTemplate" />
        </cc1:Column>
        <cc1:Column ID="Storage_type" DataField="Storage_type" HeaderText="Storage Type"
            Visible="false" Width="0%" Align="center" Wrap="true">
        </cc1:Column>
        <cc1:Column ID="Damaged_Qty" DataField="Damaged_Qty" HeaderText="Damaged Qty in Units"
            Visible="true" Width="5%" Align="center" Wrap="true">
            <TemplateSettings TemplateId="PlainEditTemplate" />
        </cc1:Column>
        <cc1:Column ID="Short_Fall_Excess" DataField="Short_Fall_Excess" HeaderText="Shortfall/ excess qty in units"
            Visible="true" Width="5%" Align="center" Wrap="true">
            <TemplateSettings TemplateId="PlainEditTemplate" />
        </cc1:Column>
    </Columns>
    <Templates>
        <cc1:GridTemplate runat="server" ID="PlainEditTemplate">
            <Template>
                <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtconfirm" CssClass="excel-textbox" onfocus="markAsFocused(this)"
                    onblur="markAsBlured(this)" />
            </Template>
        </cc1:GridTemplate>
    </Templates>
    <AddEditDeleteSettings AddLinksPosition="Bottom" NewRecordPosition="Dynamic" />
    <Templates>
        <cc1:GridTemplate runat="server" ID="GridTemplate1">
            <Template>
                <input id="txttemp" type="text" />
            </Template>
        </cc1:GridTemplate>
    </Templates>
    <Templates>
        <cc1:GridTemplate runat="server" ID="HTConfirm">
            <Template>
                <input type="checkbox" onclick="toggleSelection(this)" id="ChkSelector" />
            </Template>
        </cc1:GridTemplate>
        <cc1:GridTemplate runat="server" ID="gtchkConfirm">
            <Template>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="chk_grid" runat="server" />
            </Template>
        </cc1:GridTemplate>
    </Templates>
    <Templates>
        <cc1:GridTemplate runat="server" ID="TextBoxEditTemplate">
            <Template>
                <input type="text" name="TextBox1111" id="Txtconfirm<%# (Container.RecordIndex) %>"
                    class="excel-textbox" readonly="readonly" onfocus="GrdConfirmation.editWithTextBox(this)" />
            </Template>
        </cc1:GridTemplate>
        <cc1:GridTemplate runat="server" ID="tplNumbering">
            <Template>
                <b>
                    <%# (Container.RecordIndex + 1)%>
                </b>
            </Template>
        </cc1:GridTemplate>
        <cc1:GridTemplate ID="TemplateWithCheckbox">
            <Template>
                <asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="ChkID" ToolTip="<%# Container.Value %>" />
            </Template>
        </cc1:GridTemplate>
    </Templates>
</cc1:Grid>
```

My two columns are

```
<cc1:Column ID="Bx_Bg" DataField="Bx_Bg" HeaderText="Boxes/Bags" Visible="true" Width="6%"
            Align="center">
        </cc1:Column><cc1:Column ID="Damaged_Qty" DataField="Damaged_Qty" HeaderText="Damaged Qty in Units"
            Visible="true" Width="5%" Align="center" Wrap="true">
            <TemplateSettings TemplateId="PlainEditTemplate" />
        </cc1:Column>
```

**I want to be written in `GrdConfirmation_OnClientSelect()` function**

Comment: Is it the total weight of the entire column that you are validating?

Comment: @Cal279: No it is not the total weight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you just want to validate on the client side and your requirement is not specifically to manually handle this in javascript, you can do this by adding the following template:

```
<cc1:GridTemplate runat="server" ID="WeightTemplate">
    <Template>
        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtWeight" CssClass="excel-textbox" onfocus="markAsFocused(this)" onblur="markAsBlured(this)" />
        <asp:RangeValidator ID="WeightValidation" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Invalid weight" ValidationGroup="Validation" Type="Integer" ControlToValidate="txtWeight" MinimumValue="0" MaximumValue='<%# Eval("MaxWeight") %>' EnableClientScript="true"></asp:RangeValidator>
   </Template>
</cc1:GridTemplate>
```

Comment: but my `maximumvalue` will be dynamic. I just gave it for explaining purpose

Comment: Dynamic - different for each row? Maybe you can use databinding against the MaximumValue.

Comment: @coder: I've updated the code example above - if you set a max value for each row on the server side then you can use the above data binding syntax to validate each row separately.

Comment: let me try and implement that.. Is **`MaxWeight`** coming from the database

Comment: You will need to set MaxWeight yourself in whatever you are binding GrdConfirmation to.